# Making corn bread pudding from corn bread

Tags: substitutions, dessert, corn, bread-pudding

I have a large batch of corn bread that's about to go bad, a situation I'd like to salvage by turning it into corn bread pudding. Unfortunately, all of the recipes I can find online start from base ingredients, or corn muffin mix, rather than using completed corn bread as an ingredient. Recipes for bread pudding don't have this problem; they don't expect you to start from flour :)

Can I just substitute corn bread for wheat bread in a bread pudding recipe and get palatable results? I'm not at all sure. If not, what would people suggest I do to my corn bread, to turn it into corn bread pudding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort of substitute, yes. Bear in mind that cornbread has a far lower gluten content than wheat breads (zero gluten if there's no wheat flour in the recipe), and thus will not hold together quite as well. So you may wish to use slightly less of the custard base.

In addition, I've found that cornbread doesn't generally make a particularly nice sweet pudding; it's much better in a savoury application. So perhaps throw in some jalapeno and some goat cheese.